# Lost orange object selection outlines

Tags: 3d-view

2.8 - suddenly lost my 3d view orange object selection outlines in one file... can still select, but no indication of selected object. Is there some setting I can check?

Comment: In 2.79 it is Properties>Display>outline selected.

Answer (score 13):

Could be you have disabled **Display Overlays..........**

[image]

Or in the **Overlays** menu you have unchecked the **Outline Selected** option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Didn't realize that that was a toggle button up there. (And the overlays menus still work, even when it's turned off.)

Comment: @JoeWeisman - in addition to "thanks", please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/482681) the answer.